# Current selection does not contain a unique column. Mysqli. Duplication?

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't seem to select/retrieve the "Package Table" and merge it into 1 table that contains the other table which is "Events Table". I don't know what seems to be the problem though.

Whenever i tried to execute my query and the only thing that pops up is the 
events_ table, the Package table on the other hand does not. I tried another another simple query,

```
SELECT *  FROM event_table JOIN package ON event_id WHERE cusact_id = 8 AND event_id=80
```

And the query works fine.

Event Table (Structure):
http://prntscr.com/gbr6vr

Package Table (Structure):
https://prnt.sc/gbr793

Note: I have a column named package_id on events_table and package. Is that the problem? Im sorry, still new to mysql.

side note:

```
$c_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
$n_id = $_GET['n_id'];
$p_id = $_GET['new_p_id'];
```

all of these has data, so no problem here.

Here is my query:

```
<?php
 session_start();

  include_once 'order.confirmation-header.php';

  include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';


$c_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
$n_id = $_GET['n_id'];
$p_id = $_GET['new_p_id'];

$sql = "
        SELECT event_id, event_name, event_date, event_time_start, 
        event_time_end, cusact_id, theme, reserve_date, reserve_time  
        FROM event_table as e 
        INNER JOIN package as p 
        ON e.package_id = p.package_id 
        WHERE cusact_id = $c_id  AND event_id=$n_id
";

$data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!$data){
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't requesting any of the package columns (by merge the table I assume you mean retrieve a record set)

```
SELECT event_id, event_name, event_date, event_time_start, 
event_time_end, cusact_id, theme, reserve_date, reserve_time, p.*  
FROM event_table as e 
INNER JOIN package as p 
ON e.package_id = p.package_id 
WHERE cusact_id = $c_id  
AND event_id=$n_id
```

Your code is wide open to SQL injection, and I'd really consider using the PDO API with a prepared statement.

Comment: *"I thought the mysqli functions were deprecated in PHP7, but obviously not, they should be though"* - That IMHO, should be removed from the answer. There isn't anything wrong with using that api, it's simply a preference that not everyone shares. Edit: this as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45827988/1

Comment: Done, I added it because there are hundreds of questions on here with lots of learners using those functions, and it just isn't the way to go and hasn't been for a very long time

Comment: Thanks Lee; I made an additional edit. Using PDO on its own doesn't safeguard against sql injections; with a prepared statement does ;-)